For the polos and jumpers categories when I press it the items stored underneath they don't appear. How would I fix this issue?
class BuyItemPage:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Existing code...

        # Create a Treeview widget
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(master)
        self.treeview.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        # Fetch and display items from the database
        self.fetch_items_from_database()



    def fetch_items_from_database(self):
        try:
            # Create an instance of the Database class
            db = Database()

            # Fetch all items from the database
            items = db.fetch_all_items()

            # Get column names from the database
            column_names = ["Item", "SizeNumeric", "Size", "Year", "Price", "Condition"]

            # Set column headings of the Treeview
            self.treeview["columns"] = column_names
            self.treeview.heading("#0", text="Item")  # First column for item names

            for column in column_names:
                self.treeview.heading(column, text=column)



            # Dictionary to store categorized items
            categorized_items = {"Tie": [], "Blazer": [], "Polo": [], "Jumper": [], "Trousers": []}

    




            # Populate categorized_items dictionary
            for item in items:
                category = item[1]  # Assuming category is the second column in the database
                if category in categorized_items:
                    categorized_items[category].append(item[0])  # Assuming item name is the first column
                else:
                    # Handle uncategorized items
                    pass


             # Populate Treeview with categories and items
            for category, items in categorized_items.items():
                category_node = self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=category)
                for item in items:
                    self.treeview.insert(category_node, 'end', values=item)


            # Close the database connection
            db.close()

        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            # Handle any errors that occur during database interaction
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Failed to fetch items from the database: " + str(e))

so in my buy item page I got the items stored in the database and then placed it in the buy item page I then created categories and stored the corresponding item underneath each category. the code does this for all the items except polos and jumpers when I press there categories it doesn't show the items stored.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you try to print out the records returned from db.fetch_all_items() to see whether there are records with categories "Polo" and "Jumper"?
